# dataclass serializer deeply nested field transform

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, python-dataclasses

I love https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-dataclasses/#nested-dataclasses

I have a problem though. I am struggling to create a dataclass serializer that transform a deeply nested field from another source field

```json
{
    "type": "event",
    "id": "evt_XGuYWp7WuDzNxie5z16s7sGJ",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "inquiry.approved",
        "payload": {
            "data": {
                "type": "inquiry",
                "id": "inq_2CVZ4HyVg7qaboXz2PUHknAn",
                "attributes": {
                    "status": "approved",
                    "reference-id": null, <- this one specifically
                    "created-at": "2019-09-09T22:40:56.000Z",
                    "completed-at": "2019-09-09T22:44d:51.000Z",
                    "expired-at": null,
                },
            },
        },
        "created-at": "2019-09-09T22:46:27.598Z",
    },
}
```

See my hyphens in my deeply nested keys?

I can come up with all the dataclasses easily enough:

```
@dataclass
class PersonaEventPayloadDataAttributes:
    status: typing.Literal[
        "created",
        "pending",
        "completed",
        "approved",
        "declined",
        "expired",
        "failed",
    ]
    "reference-id": str

@dataclass
class PersonaEventPayloadData:
    type: str
    id: str
    attributes: PersonaEventPayloadDataAttributes


@dataclass
class PersonaEventPayload:
    data: PersonaEventPayloadData


@dataclass
class PersonaEventAttributes:
    name: typing.Literal[
        "inquiry.created",
        "inquiry.pending",
        "inquiry.completed",
        "inquiry.approved",
        "inquiry.declined",
        "inquiry.expired",
        "inquiry.failed",
    ]
    payload: PersonaEventPayload


@dataclass
class PersonaEvent:
    type: str
    id: str
    attributes: PersonaEventAttributes
```

I want to use it like this:

```py
DATA_STRUCTURE = # JSON from above

serializer = new DataclassSerializer(data=DATA_STRUCTURE,dataclass=PersonaEvent)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

But this is where my problem is of course:

```
    "reference-id": str
```

I can't have a hyphen in a property.

I'd like to know how to do this without having to write 5 different dataclass serializers in order to be able to transform my `reference-id` property, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Could you extend your example in a way that your bug is reproducible? I'm not familiar with django, so I don't know how to glue together and run the code.

Comment: @Arne I added the way I want to use it

Comment: what is the django serializer for again? sorry, I've never used it before. So is it like just a way to de/serialize dataclasses from a format such as json, or does it offer other benefits?

Comment: @rv.kvetch - yes, that's the gist. The other benefit it offers you is it allows you to transform field names using [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).